# Deactivate (?) QML Item to avoid overlapping of action areas

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

first question on Stack Oveflow here, so don't be evil! :)

Down to business: How to proceed if one has stacked elements with stacked action areas to make sure that you acton what you see and not on underlying elements?

I'm following a tutorial on Qt Quick 2.0 programming for desktop, where one makes a post-it like application with several pages to switch on.

So in the main.qml I have a "PagePanel.qml", where one have 3 "Page.qml" one on top of the other. Each one has opacity 0.0 until opacity 1.0 is forced by clicking a corresponding marker, to visualize the selected page. In the page are linked (and created) Items "Note.qml" that are sticker-notes with an area for dragging the item around and an area for writing on top.

Problem is that if I have on different pages two notes overlapping, if I try to drag or to write on a note there can be that I'm actually (without seeing it) dragging and writing on the underlying note.
In other words the action regions of the different pages remain active when switching from a page to the other.

How can one make inactive the hidden pages and act only on the visualized one?

Thank you in advance,
A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comments, if you have 3 `Page` elements on top of each other. The easiest would be to set `visible: false` to the one you want to disable and `visible: true` to the active one. This will disable all the `MouseArea` and `DropArea` in the elements that are not visible.